# Error converting .ui file not converting to .py

Tags: python, python-3.6, fatal-error, qt-designer

I am trying to use [pyuic5](https://pypi.org/project/pyuic5-tool/) to convert .ui files into .py files but my files are not found.

I used:

```sh
pyuic5 -x -o part2.py PART2.ui
pyuic5 -x PART2.ui -o part2.py
```

My file exist in E:\aor\p2. It gives the error:

```
ERROR:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyuic5.exe" -x -o pPART2.py PART2.ui': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: Well, your second line works.

Answer (score 1):

When `pyuic5` is not working, you can also use `pyuic6` to convert `.ui` file to `.py` file.

Steps:

1. First run:

   ```
   pip install pyuic6
   ```
2. When installation is completed then open folder in terminal and run the command:

   ```
   pyuic6 -x filename.ui -o filename.py
   ```